# NSURL for a downloaded or otherwise obtained file to open an iOS app with: What is its filepath?

Tags: ios

I have found that so far the path sent to `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/<GUID>/Documents/Inbox/file
```

To check that the filesystem operations that I am about to perform are indeed likely to succeed (and that the url given to me is not a location outside the sandbox), it looks like I have to do this:

```
NSString* hdurl = [[@"file://localhost/private" stringByAppendingString:NSHomeDirectory()] stringByAppendingString: @"/"];
NSString* path = url.absoluteString;
if ([path hasPrefix:hdurl]) {
    // now ready to e.g. call fopen on: [path substringFromIndex:@"file://localhost".length]
```

Now, I seem to vaguely recall (and this is probably wrong) that in the past I have seen the `file:///` style URL being used. That would clearly cause this code to fail.

How am I to know that it will always give me a `file://localhost` URL prefix?

Apple's [documentation on URLs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) is strangely missing a section on file URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `NSURL` that points to a file on the local file system is called a "file URL". To convert the `NSURL` to an `NSString` representing the file's path you use:

```
NSString *filePath = [url path];
```

To check to see if an `NSURL` represents a file URL, use:

```
BOOL isFileURL = [url isFileURL];
```

Keep in mind that if your app is passed a file URL, you will always have access to the file. There is no need to check if it starts with any prefix. Why would iOS pass you a file that you don't have access to?